# testcafe requestLogger only logs the first test in the fixture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, e2e-testing, testcafe

So I'm getting better with testcafe and one feature I'd like to learn is its RequestLogger.

So I've created an instance of it

```
    import { RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';

const logger = RequestLogger(/some reg exp/, {
    logRequestHeaders: true,
    logRequestBody: true
});

export default logger;
```

and then tried to use it on a sample test fixture:

```
fixture `REQUEST LOGGER TEST`
.requestHooks(logger);

test('should contain 204 as a status code 1', async t => {
    await t.useRole(role);
    await model.doSmth(t);
    await model.doSmthElse(t);

    console.log(logger.requests);

    await t
        .expect(logger.requests[0].response.statusCode)
        .eql(204);

    await t
        .expect(logger.requests[1].response.statusCode)
        .eql(200);
});
```

While the first test works just fine, the second one, even if it's the same, will output an empty array once I'll try to console.log(logger.requests)

Any idea how to go about it?

Comment: Please try to add the following check-up before calling console.log(logger.requests): await t.expect(logger.contains(record => record.response.statusCode === 200)).ok();

Comment: @Marion
Thanks for your comment.
Unfortunately, the assertion simply fails once the second test gets executed

Comment: Would you please provide me with a link to your site so that I can check the issue locally?

Comment: You can send a private link here: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create

Comment: @Marion thanks, I've just created a new request here:
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T672631/testcafe-requestlogger-only-logs-requests-for-the-first-test-in-the-fixture

please take a look if you can

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem because you have to wait for the Smart Assertion Query Mechanism of Testcafe before doing assertions on Logger.request array.

The [documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/logging-http-requests.html#logger-methods) tells us that using count or contains predicates make Testcafe use the [Smart Assertion Query mechanism](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/#smart-assertion-query-mechanism)

Suggestion from Marion may do the job if your request returns a 200 statusCode :

```
await t.expect(logger.contains(record => record.response.statusCode === 200)).ok();
```

I found simpler to do this instead, which does not depend on the returned http status

```
await t.expect(logger.count(() => true)).eql(1);
```

replace eql(1) with the number of requests you expect to be logged before doing your assertions